# How do I ensure my JS ERB is Turbolinks 5 friendly?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, turbolinks, ruby-on-rails-5

I have some simple JS ERB files that work perfectly the first time around. However, the issue is that when the trigger for the JS is pressed multiple times, it doesn't work client-side (even though it works server-side) - which I suspect is related to Turbolinks 5.

One such example of my JS.erb is this:

```
$("#a-<%= @answer.id %>-accept-answer i.accepted-answer-checkbox.fa.fa-check-square-o").addClass('fa-check-square voted');
$("#a-<%= @answer.id %>-accept-answer i.accepted-answer-checkbox.fa.fa-check-square-o").removeClass('fa-check-square-o');
```

That's in my `Questions` controller & `/questions/accept_answer.js.erb`.

But, right now, my `questions.coffee` file is blank.

What's the best way to tackle this?

Comment: It's not clear what's your problem. Can you add more related code and explain what should be happening and is not?

Comment: I would suggest simply removing turbo links. Unless you're specifically optimising against turbolinks, it seems to always create more problems than it solves. This is of course just my own opinion. 

Additionally, I'm also a little confused about what you're specific problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, CoffeeScript has Ruby-style interpolation, so the easiest way to convert those would be to just go and do something like

```
$("#a-#{@answer.id}-accept-answer i.accepted-answer-checkbox.fa.fa-check-square-o").addClass 'fa-check-square voted'
$("#a-#{@answer.id}-accept-answer i.accepted-answer-checkbox.fa.fa-check-square-o").removeClass 'fa-check-square-o'
```

But what you're trying to *do*, would probably be better served by toggling those three classes, having them in an initial state that opposes each other, so something like:

```
$("#a-#{@answer.id}-accept-answer i.accepted-answer-checkbox.fa").click (el) ->
  $.each ['fa-check-square', 'voted', 'fa-check-square-o'], (_, val) ->
    $(el).find('i.accepted-answer-checkbox.fa').toggleClass val
```

Of course, I could be making it too complex, but this seems to solve the problem of toggling the classes that are desired.

Comment: That doesn't quite solve my problem of this only working on the first load, and not on subsequent Turbolinks page loads though. How do I prevent this from not working when a `page:load` Turbolinks event is fired?

Comment: According to [this page](https://coderwall.com/p/whhuhw/migrating-jquery-for-use-in-a-turbolinks-application), you *should* be able to bind that to a `jQuery(document).on 'ready page:load', ->`